Trigger AWS Step Function from EventBridge Rule
I have implemented the AWS S3 Malware GuardDuty protection as detailed https://github.com/aws-samples/guardduty-malware-protection/tree/main/cdk, the events are being triggered when a file is uploaded. I have also created an additional Rule that will trigger an AWS StepFunction, but this seems not to trigger. I have used the payload as document here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/guardduty/latest/ug/monitor-with-eventbridge-s3-malware-protection.html
Here is part of the code:
    // Workflow
    const workflowStack = new WorkflowStack(this, "Workflow", {
      config: props.config,
      bucketArn: sftpBucket.bucketArn
    });

    const guardDutyNoMalwareRule = new Rule(
      this,
      "GuardDutyMalwareScanResultRule",
      {
        eventPattern: {
          source: ["aws.guardduty"],
          detailType: ["GuardDuty Malware Protection Object Scan Result"],
          detail: {
            scanResultDetails: {
              scanResultStatus: ["NO_THREATS_FOUND"],
            },
          },
        },
      },
    );

    guardDutyNoMalwareRule.addEventPattern({
      detail: {
        responsePayload: {
          input_key: [
            {
              "anything-but": { wildcard: ["results/*"] },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    });

    guardDutyNoMalwareRule.addTarget(
      new SfnStateMachine(workflowStack.sfn, {
        input: RuleTargetInput.fromObject({
          input_bucket: EventField.fromPath(
            "$.detail.s3ObjectDetails.bucketName",
          ),
          input_key: EventField.fromPath("$.detail.s3ObjectDetails.objectKey"),
          message: "Scan completed, no threats found.",
          source: EventField.fromPath("$.source"),
          status: EventField.fromPath(
            "$.detail.scanResultDetails.scanResultStatus",
          ),
        }),
      }),
    );


Basically I want to trigger the StepFunction when aws.guardduty with "GuardDuty Malware Protection Object Scan Result"] and scanResultStatus: ["NO_THREATS_FOUND"]
I also want to transform the input and send it to the StepFunction, but is not even triggering the step function.
Any advice is much appreciated

My pattern should have been
    guardDutyNoMalwareRule.addEventPattern({
      detail: {
        s3ObjectDetails: {
          objectKey: [
            {
              "anything-but": { wildcard: ["results/*"] },
            },
          ],
        },
        scanResultDetails: {
          scanResultStatus: ["NO_THREATS_FOUND"],
        },
      },
    });

detail.s3ObjectDetails.objectKey instead of detail.responsePayload.object-key
